# Overflow float in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

```
import java.lang.*;

import java.math.*;

public class CFloatExample
{

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: main
    // Abstract: This is where the program starts.  
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main( String astrCommandLine[] )
    {

        // Declare float variables 
    float fltMinimum = 0;
    float fltMaximum = 0;

    // Set to min/max value of float
    fltMinimum = -3.4E38F;
    fltMaximum = 3.4E38F;

    // Print min/max values for float
    System.out.print( "float Data Type------------------------------------------------\n" );
    System.out.print( "\tMinimum: " + fltMinimum + "\n" );
    System.out.print( "\tMaximum: " + fltMaximum + "\n" );
    System.out.print( "\n" );       // Blank line

    // Confirm by subtracting and adding one to int (integer)
    fltMinimum -= 1.0E0F;
    fltMaximum += 1.0E0F;
    System.out.print( "float Confirmation\n" );
    System.out.print( "\tMinimum: " + fltMinimum + "\n" );
    System.out.print( "\tMaximum: " + fltMaximum + "\n" );
    System.out.print( "\n" );       // Blank line
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the Float variable to overflow but I am not getting that result, above you can see I tried importing some libraries to see if that would cause it to happen, but in the end it just prints the same number before and after I add 1.

Comment: Well the code you've given won't even compile, as you haven't declared `fltMinimum` and `fltMaximum`...

Comment: Sorry I removed alot of unrelated code, I quess i removed too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sufficiently large `float`s, adding `1` won't do anything: they're so large that they get rounded back down to their original value.

To understand this, let's say you're storing a decimal value with 5 decimal digits of precision, and you have 1000000.  If you add 1, you *would* get 1000001, but since you only have five digits of precision, it rounds back to 1000000.

You'll have to add something bigger.

What you can do is test that `Math.nextUp(Float.MAX_VALUE) == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, which I suspect is what you want to convince yourself of.

Comment: are you saying I should add 1.0E38F and -1.0E38F ?

Comment: For example 1 ulp [`Math.ulp(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28float%29) that should be the smallest thing that will make a difference

Comment: You could do that, yes?  Floats have 22 bits of precision, which comes out to ~7 decimal digits; what that means is approximately that if `x` is a float, `x += y` won't do anything if `abs(y) < abs(x) / ~10^7`.  `Math.ulp(x)` represents the difference between `x` and the next-highest representable `float` value.

Comment: Note that as `3.4E38F` is not the largest finite `float`, adding a single ulp to it will not cause an overflow (but adding enough will). Or just multiplying by `1.1F`.

Comment: when I did that I got -infinity and +infinity. I am guessing that is the answer I am looking for? lol, sorry trying to test the limits of variables to expand my knowledge a little.

Comment: That is more-or-less the answer you're looking for, though as @PascalCuoq points out, you haven't used the exact maximum representable `float`; use `Float.MAX_VALUE` instead.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html Thank you Louis Wasserman I used the information you gave me and found the link above that explained my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `strictfp` tp your class's parameter

```
public strictfp class CFloatExample { //...
```

`strictfp` makes the class to always use fixed decimal points for `float` and `double`. For more information on that, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp

Comment: Absence of `strictfp` does not cause the OP's problem, as seen by adding `strictfp` to their code and still observing that `1.0F` is absorbed by `3.4E38F`.